# CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: laravel, cors, axios, laravel-vue

full error message :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api_url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I cannot fixed this cors problem .

my vue component code :

```
test(){
  axios.get("https://api_url")
  .then(response => {
        this.data = response.data.data;
  });
}
```

I also create a middleware & add it to protected array `$middleware` in `Kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package and it will solve your problem
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: where i can't see it's implementation

Comment: i used it , but not working . i remove it from protected array `$middleware` in `Kernel.php`

Comment: can you show me how you used it.
if you are using api you just need to app it to api middlewares

Comment: yes , i add these line . `'api' => [
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandlePreflight::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],`

Comment: please correct it to `\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class` and put it in the last of api array middlewares

Comment: it's not `HandlePreflight`

Comment: do you have any way to share your screen ? any desk, teamviewer?

Comment: yes. I have Teamviewer . ID : 1 654 017 422 , Password : 5i51ay

Answer (score 0):

Use this package like @Mohammed Aktaa suggested: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Add the `HandleCors` middleware to your `api` `$middlewareGroup` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
'api' => [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
],
```

Publish the configuration of the package:

```sh
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

Edit the configuration to use the CORS_ORIGIN environment variable for the allowed origin:

```
'allowedOrigins' => [env('CORS_ORIGIN', '')],
```

In your .env file, add an entry for your local origin:

```
CORS_ORIGIN="http://localhost:3000"
```